# number_with_precision called on attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My boli model has an attribute current, which is an integer.

When I publish the current value, it's not showing the decimal points.

And when I add number_with_precision it shows zeros instead of the actual numbers.

The number in the column is 10.78.  When I publish the number is shows 10.00.

Below is my html code.  I've also tried number_to_currency, but with the same results.  Any idea how I can get the current attribute to show the decimal points?

```
  <div class="ratings"> 
    <b>Current BOLI:</b> 
    <%=number_with_precision(boli.current, precision: 2) %> 
  </div>
```

*Thank you ruby community.*

Comment: can you tell me what it shows in the schema file for `boli.current`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case I would make sure not to use a integer but instead to use a decimal.

change_column :bolis, :current,  :decimal

I believe that is all you should need and you will be ok. 
I would also then recorded in looking at the **precision** and **scale** option that go with decimal

- **precision** Defines the precision for the decimal fields, representing the total number of digits in the number.
- **scale** Defines the scale for the decimal fields, representing the number of digits after the decimal point.

for more info look at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks @MZaragoza!  I tried changing it before to decimal, but what I wasn't doing was resetting the database and running migrations again.  Thanks for your help.